# Unable to retrieve value from function Javascript/Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gcloud

I am trying to insert a user's username, and then I am trying to get their user_id (which is auto incremented in the MySQL table) inserted into the Party table as seen within the below code. Whenever I console log the results from the selectUserID, I get the user_id without any issues at all.

Whenever I try to put the user_id into the insertPokemon function, it will not work at all. If I hard code a value it obviously works, but if I use this, get_id will always try to enter an "undefined" value, and it will not allow any insertion at all. I am not having any issues at all when inserting just the username with the insertUser function.  Does anyone know how I can pass the selectUserID results/user_id into the insertPokemon function?  I have tried passing the results to a variable without any luck as well.

Additional note: When I console.log(results) it returns the correct integer that I am wanting, but when I actually return results, it is always undefined.

```
require('dotenv').config();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const connection = require('./db');
const path = require(`path`);

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port 8081`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/form.html'));
});

app.post('/submit', async (req, res, next) => {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var pokemon1 = req.body.pokemon1;
    var pokemon2 = req.body.pokemon2;
    var pokemon3 = req.body.pokemon3;
    var pokemon4 = req.body.pokemon4;
    var pokemon5 = req.body.pokemon5;
    var pokemon6 = req.body.pokemon6;

    await insertUser(username, function(){
        console.log(`In insertUser callback!`);
    });

    // get userID

    const get_id = await selectUserID(function(results){
        results = JSON.stringify(results);
        console.log(results);
        return results;
    });

    await insertPokemon(get_id, pokemon1, pokemon2, pokemon3, pokemon4, pokemon5, pokemon6, function(){
        console.log('In insertPokemon callback!');
        res.status(200).send("Added pokemon for user" + get_id);
    });
});

app.get('/party', async (req, res, next) => {
    await selectPokemon(function(results){
        res.status(200).send(results);
    });
});


// Helper functions
const insertUser = async function(un, callback){
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO Users (Username)
    VALUES ("${un}")`,
    function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        callback(results);
    });
}

const insertPokemon = async function(uid, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, callback) {
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO Party (User_ID, Pokemon_1, Pokemon_2, Pokemon_3, Pokemon_4, Pokemon_5, Pokemon_6)
    VALUES (${uid}, "${p1}", "${p2}", "${p3}", "${p4}", "${p5}", "${p6}")`,
    function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        callback(results);
    });
}

const selectPokemon = async function(callback) {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM Party`, function(error, results, fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        callback(results);
    });
}

const selectUserID = async function(callback) {
    connection.query(`SELECT MAX(User_ID) FROM Users`, function(error, results, fields){
        if (error) throw error;
        callback(results[0]["MAX(User_ID)"]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code. You're misunderstanding what `async/await` do. There is no promises in your code but you still use `async/await`.

If you really want to write: `await selectUserID` , this method should return a Promise.

Promise are here to avoid `callback` functions.

An example to get your `userId`:

```
const selectUserID = async function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    connection.query(`SELECT MAX(User_ID) FROM Users`, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(results[0]["MAX(User_ID)"]);
    });
  })
}
```

Another point, be careful to your SQL requests: if you do it these way, you risk SQL Injection attacks.